# Create service principal programmatically in Azure Python API

Tags: python, azure, rbac, service-principal

How can I, using the Azure Python API, create a full set of credentials that can later be used to start and deallocate all  VMs in a named resource group, without any other permissions?

I have thoroughly researched the example code and both official and unofficial documentation, but I don't even know where to start...

I know I will need a tenant ID, client ID, client secret and subscription ID. Which of those can I make using an API, and how would I go about assigning roles to allow for starting/deallocating VMs of an existing resource group?

Sample code highly sought after, but will take any hint!

Comment: it would be so much easier doing this manually. why do you want to créate service principal in code when its a 1 time thing?

Comment: Because, why do a computer's job? My program sets up custom tailored clusters from scratch, and this is the last step. If user intervention i required it defeats the purpose of the app.

Comment: Well its not for automation's sake :) *phew* I guess I'm lucky!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `azure-graphrbac` package to create a Service Principal:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/activedirectory

The closer to a sample might be this unittest:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/graphrbac/azure-graphrbac/tests/test_graphrbac.py

For role and permissions, you need `azure-mgmt-authorization`:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/authorization

Best sample for this one, is probably the sub-part of this sample:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-python-msi-vm#role-assignement-to-the-msi-credentials

"msi_identity" is a synonym of "service principal" in your context.

Note that all of this is supported by the CLI v2.0:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/ad/sp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/role/assignment

It might be interested to test the CLI in `--debug` mode and sniffing in the code repo at the same time:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli

(full disclosure, I work at MS in the Azure SDK for Python team)

Comment: Updated link for the first unittest: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/graphrbac/azure-graphrbac/tests/test_graphrbac.py

Comment: @Laurent, Can Microsoft add more description and comments in their unittest and SDK modules docs? It seems like there is nothing in code or on any packages or modules at all.

Comment: Could you create an issue in the azure sdk for python repo asking for more doc and things you need? Thanks! https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Comment: @LaurentMazuel I was looking at the role assignment step in your answer. I see that the authorization_client.role_assignments.create() is taking in a res_group_id,role_assign_name and a role_assign_parameter) However, I was looking at the offical doc at learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-authorization/azure.mgmt.authorization.v2018_09_01_preview.operations.roleassignmentsoperations?view=azure-python#create-scope--role-assignment-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config- I see it's take a parameter called 'scope' instead of the 'res_group_id'?

Comment: The scope can be any REST resource instance. For example, use '/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/' for a subscription, '/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}' for a resource group. So res_group_id is a valid scope

Comment: @LaurentMazuel I tried the test code you provided above, but once I tried it I got hit by this exception " raise models.GraphErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." do know what should I do?

Comment: You need to discuss with your Azure admin, as the message says there is insufficient permissions for this operation.

Comment: @LaurentMazuel, what permission levels are required to create a service principal programmatically via the python SDK? I had to have GA create this. Would be nice to know what the minimum perm level is so we can enable a more self-service solution. Thank you.

Comment: @LennartRolland, did you ever get a solution put together here? It would be of great benefit to share.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still arriving at this question, python's `azure-rbac` has been deprecated since [December 20, 2022](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/pull/27229) (but not widely documented, at the time of this comment).

Seems like the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/ad/sp) is the best solution right now , with Graph API being another possible course but that's also not very documented.