# azure python - create service principal

Tags: python, azure, clientid, service-principal

Python script that has to create Azure service principal and get the tenant ID, client ID and secret.

Is there any support API that I can bring the required details.

Comment: And I have to assign contributor role to service principal

Comment: You can follow this case [Create service principal programmatically in Azure Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958126/create-service-principal-programmatically-in-azure-python-api).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and you can refer to "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).