# What is needed for ServicePrincipalsOperations parameters?

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, service-principal

I'm attempting to programmatically register Service Principals in Azure AD using Python. It looks like I should be using the [`ServicePrincipalsOperations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.operations.serviceprincipalsoperations?view=azure-python#parameters) class, however the documentation does not clearly outline what is needed for the parameters. It appears that it is expecting data from other classes within `azure.graphrbac`, but the documentation is unclear.

I think I should be using the `azure.graphrbac.GraphRbacManagementClient` to generate the client parameter for `ServicePrincipalsOperations`, but that's just a guess at this point.

Similarly, I suspect that I would need to use `azure.graphrbac.models.ServicePrincipalCreateParameters` for the config parameter.

Has anyone successfully registered a Service Principal using Python that may be able to shed more light on these parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you can use [this test](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/graphrbac/azure-graphrbac/tests/test_graphrbac.py) as a reference, but the documents [do specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.models.serviceprincipalcreateparameters?view=azure-python) what you need to pass in to the method to create a service principal.

Sample code:

```
self.graphrbac_client.service_principals.create({
    'app_id': app.app_id, # Do NOT use app.object_id
    'account_enabled': False
})
```

More reading: [Create service principal programmatically in Azure Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958126/create-service-principal-programmatically-in-azure-python-api)