# Where can I find Service Principal GUID from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-sdk-python

I need to create a service principal and assign a new role to it through `Python` SDK. I am currently following steps as listed from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958126/create-service-principal-programmatically-in-azure-python-api).

I am currently working on the role assignment and I am stuck on the step of I need to input a `principal_id`. For example, as needed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-authorization/azure.mgmt.authorization.v2018_09_01_preview.models.roleassignmentcreateparameters?view=azure-python) to create a new role assignment. Where can I find this service `principal id` in `Azure` portal? Is it the `appId` or `objectId` under `Azure` Portal-> Active Directory -> App Registration -> My app?

Comment: Did you check in app registration in AAD?

Comment: I just made an update to my question. Yes I am looking at the app registration in AAD. What I am confused about is which Id for my app is corresponding to the principal_id it's asking here. Is it the appId or the objectId for my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I am confused about is which Id for my app is corresponding to
>   the principal_id it's asking here. Is it the appId or the objectId for
>   my app?

None of these. There should be a service principal tied to the application. That will have an ID.

[image]

PS. The screenshot is of the App Registration blade in the Azure portal.

Comment: Yeah, the object id of the service principal (aka enterprise app, aka managed app in local directory) is what is required.

Comment: To clarify, when you click on the link next to *"Manage application in ..."* above, you're taken to the *Enterprise Application | Overview* panel. There, under *Properties*, you'll see the *Object ID* field. That field's value is the *Service Principal ID* you're looking for.

Comment: You have no idea how much I searched for this in Microsoft's documentation and couldn't find anything. I kept going to the "Enterprise Applications" menu directly and couldn't see any listed service applications. But from the application object "Managed application in local directory" link as you suggested, it was there. Thank you.

Comment: they should, actually, be under "Enterprise Application", you might need to toggle a switch in that view that shows all apps, not just created by MS or by You, dont remember exactly